# How do you prevent specific tags from being pushed to Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: docker, nexus

For local development, I use `:local` as the tag name for a Docker image.   I want Sonatype Nexus to prevent accidental pushes of an image with a `:local` tag.  How can this be done?

Comment: Although I have never tried, it might be possible to target specific tags on docker registries with [Content selectors](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/access-control/content-selectors) (see also the [Specific doc for docker](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/content-selectors-and-docker)). Meanwhile, if I see pretty well how you can try to allow only a certain population to write specific tags, doing the opposite (disallow) would probably end up listing all the possible allowed tags except `:local`... quite a pain.

Comment: How would you differentiate accidental from intentional?